# How to share images across different .NET project types? (WPF, MAUI)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, maui

We are working on a new project and we're trying to put all of our images into one assembly.

```
Core.Images.csproj
- PNG
-- Image1.png
-- Image2.png
- SVG
-- Image1.svg
-- Image2.svg
```

Our main application will be a WPF application. We intend to use DevExpress and want to use their `SplashScreenManager` which requires a `DXSplashScreenViewModel`. The only option to put a logo into this ViewModel is an `Uri` object. As far as I know this pretty common for WPF applications.
The intended URI format is something like this: `pack://application:,,,/Core.Images;component/PNG/Image2.png`
But this only works as long as the `PropertyGroup` inside of Core.Images.csproj has the build target set to net6.0-windows and UseWpf enabled.
Also the files **must** be set as "Resource".

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="PNG\Image1.png" />
    <Resource Include="PNG\Image2.png" />
    <Resource Include="SVG\Image1.svg" />
    <Resource Include="SVG\Image2.svg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
```

The issue we come across now is that we need to add another app to the solution that is developed in .NET MAUI.
We have been trying to make this little assembly compatible to both projects, but can't seem to find a way.

Is it even possible to achieve that with one library or will we need to copy used images to a second assembly?

Comment: What platform(s) does your MAUI app target?

Comment: We're currently targeting Windows tablets with our MAUI app, but there are vague plans to replace those with Android tablets in the future.

Comment: Since the Windows target in MAUI is more specific than net6.0-windows,your answer might still work. I will try it on Monday and get back to you with feedback. Thanks for taking your time so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are targeting Android in your MAUI app, your Core.Images.csproj should look something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows;net6.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows'">
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows'">
    <Resource Include="Images\image.png" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">
    <MauiImage Include="Images\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You should deal with other platforms too. I hope this is helpful, works on my side. Feel free to ask If somethink is not understabdable. Note, that your images names can only contain lowercase lettering, digits and '_'.

Comment: This answer helped me edit our project accordingly to our needs.

What I adjusted:
- added `net6.0` and **`net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0`** as target frameworks
- changed conditions for MAUI to `'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0-windows' And '$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0'` (on both the `PropertyGroup` and the `ItemGroup`)
- added an `<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0'">` that copies the images as content

I would like to suggest an edit for the answer, but I get a message, that there are too many suggested edits on Stack Overflow right now.